# How to make last element in python for loop increment one last time

Tags: python

in Python:

```
ele = 0
for ele in range(0,4):
    print('-')
print(ele)
```

I realized that this will print 3 instead of 4 in the end, which is different from C-style for loop. is `while` the option to achieve C-style behavior?

Comment: Why not `print(ele+1)`?

Comment: Why can't you just use `for ele in range(1,5):`?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? If you want to know whether or not the loop stopped prematurely because of a break, you can use `for .... else ...` where the else clause will only be executed if the loop wasn't terminated using a `break`. (In C you would check the value of ele and if it is 4, you'd know the loop wasn't terminated using a break, hence this suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Try `else`. Statements under `else` will be executed **exactly once** after the code gets out of the loop.

```
for ele in range(0,4):
    print('-')
else:
    ele=ele+1
print(ele)
```

Output:

```
-
-
-
-
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an independent variable to count the loop iterations with `enumerate()`:

```
N = 4
items = range(0, N)
i = 0
for i, x in enumerate(items, 1):
    print(i, ":", x)
print("number of loop iterations done:", i)
```

You should make sure to reset the value before the loop, as it is not set to zero, when the loop did not iterate even once.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

`for ele in range(param1, param2)`, it means *param1 <= ele < param2*

if you want to get the value of param2, you might change the value bigger than param2.

Answer (score 0):

```
ele = 0
for ele in range(0,4):
    print('-')
print(ele+1)
```

Comment: this wont work for me, as i intend result to stay 0 if loop is not executed

Answer (score 0):

In python the range function works differently, if you want to print something N times try this:

```
ele = 0
for i in range(N):
    print("-")
print(ele)
```

Also is not the only approach you could take for printing, you can also:

```
print("-\n"*(N-1) + "-" + ele)
```

The **range()** function works in different ways:

1. range(N) which means a list from 0 to N-1, i.e, a list containing N elements
2. range(A,B) which means a list from integer A to integer B
3. range(A,B,k) which means a list starting from integer A ending before B and with increments k

You can also refer to the official documents: 
[docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Hope this helps :D!

Answer (score 0):

A `for` with a `range` is roughly equivalent to a `for` on a list, i.e. your loop could also be written as:

```
for ele in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
    print('-')
```

If you want `ele` to be equal to the number of loops after executing the `for` instruction, you could also write:

```
for ele in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    print('-')
```

which can be rewritten using `range` as:

```
for ele in range(1, 5):
    print('-')
```

since `range` goes from the first parameter to the number immediately before the second parameter.